# How to write the thin font in the picture?

Tags: fonts

[image]

How to write the thin font like the letters in the red boxes?

Comment: Looks like Courier, a monospaced font, to me. Give `\usepackage{courier}` (or `\usepackage[Scaled=1.05]{couriers}`) and `\texttt{In}`. \texttt{out}`, etc a try.

Comment: @Mico That works. Thanks.

Comment: In the modern toolchain,with `fontspec`, you could `\setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}` and then use `\texttt{In}`, etc.